# std::format %z specifier not working for local_time

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

I want to get a timestamp in the format "YYYY-MM-DD hh::mm::ss.fff +zz".

I thought I could do this with the [`%z` specifier for `std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/local_t/formatter#:%7E:text=Writes%20the%20offset%20from%20UTC%20in%20the%20ISO%208601%20format.%20For%20example%20%2D0430%20refers%20to%204%20hours%2030%20minutes%20behind%20UTC.%20If%20the%20offset%20is%20zero%2C%20%2B0000%20is%20used.) but I'm getting this error on MSVC:

```
error C7595: 'std::basic_format_string<char,const std::chrono::time_point<
std::chrono::local_t,std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::system_clock::rep,std::chrono::system_clock::period>> &>::basic_format
_string': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
```

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

std::string get_current_time_and_date() {
  auto const time =
      std::chrono::current_zone()->to_local(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
  return std::format("{:%F %T %z}", time);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << get_current_time_and_date() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

If I use `"{:%F %T}"` as the format string, it works fine (but obviously does not include the time zone). This tells me that the error message is nonsensical, but is there some way around this? Is this a bug in the compiler?

---

For posterity, here's a workaround using good old `strftime`:

```cpp
std::string get_current_time_and_date() {
  auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                time.time_since_epoch()) %
            1000;
  auto localT = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time);
  std::tm timeStruct;
  localtime_s(&timeStruct, &localT);
  std::ostringstream oss;
  const size_t TIME_STR_LEN = 32;

  char buf[TIME_STR_LEN];
  std::strftime(buf, TIME_STR_LEN, "%F %T", &timeStruct);

  char timezonebuf[16];
  std::strftime(timezonebuf, sizeof(timezonebuf), " %z", &timeStruct);

  oss << buf << '.' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << ms.count() << timezonebuf;
  return oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::chrono::time_zone::to_local`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_zone/to_local) returns an `std::chrono::local_time`, which is an `std::chrono::time_point` that uses an `std::chrono::local_t` as its first template argument. However, a quote from [`std::chrono::local_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/local_t) on cppreference (emphasis mine):

> The class `local_t` is a **pseudo-clock** /…/ to indicate that the time point represents local time with respect of a **not-yet-specified time zone**.

In other words, such a timepoint (that the `std::chrono::time_zone::to_local` returns) is timezone-agnostic, it does not contain any information about the timezone used.

If you try and change

```cpp
return std::format("{:%F %T %z}", time);
```

to

```cpp
return std::vformat("{:%F %T %z}", std::make_format_args(time));
```

you'll see it throws an `std::format_error` with the description *"format argument does not contain the information required by the chrono-specs"*.

There is a remark (#13) in the [draft standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/time.format#13):

> If `%Z`, `%z`, or a modified version of `%z` is used, an exception of type `format_error` is thrown.

In other words, `%z` is not supported for `local_time` (because the time zone info is not contained in the `local_time` anyway).

---

As suggested by Barry, perhaps [`std::choro::zoned_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/zoned_time) is what you had in mind instead. It does allow the `%z` specifier. Here is a modified example:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string get_current_time_and_date()
{
    const auto zt{ std::chrono::zoned_time{
        std::chrono::current_zone(),
        std::chrono::system_clock::now() } };
    return std::format("{:%F %T %z}", zt);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << get_current_time_and_date() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Can add that what OP probably wanted wasn't `current_zone()->to_local(now)` but rather `zoned_time(current_zone(), now)`, which does work with that specifier.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for the suggestion, I've added an example.

Answer (score 2):

At [heap underrun explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76543544/7582247), you can't use `%z` with `std::chrono::local_time`s. You can however work around that by extracting the offset from the time zone's [`std::chrono::local_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/local_info).

Example:

```cpp
std::string get_current_time_and_date() {
    auto const time = std::chrono::current_zone()->to_local(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    auto zi = std::chrono::current_zone()->get_info(time);
    bool neg = false;
    auto offset = zi.first.offset; // see note below
    if (offset < std::chrono::seconds{}) {
        offset = -offset;
        neg = true;
    }
    return std::format("{:%F %T} {}{:%H%M}", time, neg ? '-' : '+', offset);
}
```

Note: Read the documentation for `std:.chrono::local_info`. You may need to check `zi.result` too.

Comment: Plus one from me, I think your answer does have useful info. (I don't know who voted this down; not me.)

Comment: @heapunderrun Thanks! It's clearly not as useful as your answer, but still, it may have piece in it that may be useful to someone :-)